# How to create just a view in odoo9 that does not save data in a model?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-view

I am working in odoo9. Now I needed a view that permits the user to select partner and get his sale history.

Now I created a model "sale.history" but it saves the selected data as a record in db. I really don't need this.

How can I create a view for this.

[Please also see this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rh72J.png)

Answer (score 1):

You have two options for such views/reports.

1. Use `TransientModel` instead of `Model` for the model inheritance. Transient model records in database will be deleted by a frequently running cron job. The email message PopUp/Wizard is a nice example for that.
2. Write your own report (database view) for sales order. Actually there already is one report for that: Reporting/Sales/Sales Analysis. The model for that report is `sale.report` if you want to know, how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from using a `TransientModel` (old api) or `AbstractModel` (new api)...you can simply set the `store` property of field to false, that way your field will never be persisted to the database, it will simply be a 'view field'.

```
class sale_history(model.Model):
    _name='sale.history'

    partner = fields.Many2one('res.partner', store=False)
```

The partner field will never get saved to the database

Answer (score 0):

You can use store=False on the field in the model (as danidee suggested).

You can also overwrite the create method on the model.

Question - what is the purpose of the "sale.history" model? If it does not store any data at all then you may be better off creating a new view against "res.partner" rather than creating a new model.